# If $\frac{1}{x+y} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$, find $(\frac{x}{y})^6 + (\frac{x}{y})^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I tried really hard to solve the problem. But I didn't get it. The answer is also apparently, a rational number. I'd really appreciate the answer with the process.

Comment: Let $x = a y$ for some number $a$, then work with that.

Comment: The x and y that satisfies this equation are non real numbers...it can be seen from the graph

Comment: Call $t=x/y$. The equation given tells that $t^2+t+1=0$. You want to compute $t^6+t^3$. Divide this polynomial by $t^2+t+1$. If should give $(t^6+t^3)=(t^2+t+1)q(t)+r(t)$, where $q(t)$ is the quotient and $r(t)$ is the remainder. Note that $(t^2+t+1)q(t)=0$. So, your value is $r(t)$. You could solve for $t$ in $t^2+t+1$ and substitute it in $r(t)$, but it turns out that $r(t)=2$. So, no need to compute $t$.

Comment: @xpaul It is not me the one asking. Talk to them.

Answer (score 3):

So basically, now that x and y are non zero, we can simplify the equation $$x^2+y^2+xy=0$$ and hereby it confirms that $\frac{x}{y}$ is $3$rd root of unity, so apparently answer should be $$\boxed{2}$$